# Styled components - How do I create a style that inherits a component and is able to send props to the parent?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

As an example *(not real, but works the same way)*, I have two components, one *(the parent)* has the styles and calls a function in one of them:

**Component 1**

```js
import { callFunctionToResolve } from 'resolver';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styled = {
  Component1: styled.div`
    background-color: ${({ backgroundColor }) => callFunctionToResolve(backgroundColor};
    color: ${({ textColor })};
    // ...
  `
};

const Component1 = ({ children, styles }) => {
  const { backgroundColor, textColor } = styles;

  return (
    <Styled.Component1
      backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
      textColor={textColor}
    >
      {children}
   </Styled.Component1>
  );
};
```

And now I have my **Component 2** which has the exact same css's as **Component 1**, but changes `div` to something else, adds a `display` property, and will also receive the `styles` props.

```js
import { Component1 } from 'component1';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styled = {
  Component2: styled(Component1)`
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
  `
};

const Component2 = ({ children, styles }) => (
  <Styled.Component2
    as={'header'}
    styles={styles}
  >
    {children}
  </Styled.Component2>
);
```

The problem is that `Component1` isn't receiving the `Component2` props. What is the best way to do this?

Note that more components will inherit from `Component1`.

Link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-sound-ufeg0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`className` prop in order to apply injected styles](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components) and remove the `as` prop as it overrides.

You can't use `as` and `styled(Component)` together.

```
const Component1 = ({ className, children, styles }) => {
  const { backgroundColor, textColor } = styles;

  return (
    <Styled.Component1
      className={className}
      backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
      textColor={textColor}
    >
      {children}
    </Styled.Component1>
  );
};

const Component2 = ({ children, styles, className }) => (
  <Styled.Component2 className={className} styles={styles}>
    {children}
  </Styled.Component2>
);
```

[image: Edit unruffled-proskuriakova-gmrmt]

Comment: I should've specified that many components will inherit from this component. So `Component3` and `Component4` will also be calling `styled(Component1)`. I might've miss understood the answer though.

Comment: Just check the link, add `className` prop to `Component1`

Comment: I've added it but nothing seems to change. Am I supposed to type a specific `className` myself?

Comment: No, just recreate the problem in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)

Comment: And also try checking a visible style like border or something.

Comment: I'm trying but for some reason am not being able to add props to the styled component part even though I added the dependency.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-sound-ufeg0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark I think I was able to do it.

Comment: I see the mistake, you made a salad there, let me fix it

Comment: I'll be waiting for the salad remix

Comment: It seems to be working but how would I go to define `Component2` as an header (or something else) in this case then?

Comment: Thats not the use case for this. Use the styles of a header, or use css blocks. Either way its entirely new question that you should ask.